# Cocos2D - iPhone - Sprite won't show when created in an instance method

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, runtime-error, sprite

So in my project, I call an instance method called "-(void)fire" in the class "Survival.m":

```
-(void)fire {


NSLog(@"Firing");



CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bullet.png"];
sprite.position = player.position;
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(player.position));

[self addChild:sprite z:100];


}
```

When I do this, the sprite doesn't show on the screen.
The method is being called from another layer but since it logs "Firing" every time I tap the button, it's not the problem.

I am using a TMXTiledMap as well if that could cause any problems.
Please help, thanks!

**EDIT---------**

I can create sprites in the other layer, HUDLayer but not in the Survival layer which  contains the player and the tiled map. If I create a sprite in the "init" method, it works correctly but If i do it in the method "fire" it doesn't work. The method "fire" is being called from the HUDLayer but I still now the method is being called since I see in the log that it says "Firing"

Could it be that:
1. The sprite is being created out of sight?
2. The sprite is not being created?
3. The sprite is not added to the correct parent?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say you are calling the method from another Layer, if so have you added the Survival layer to the other Layer? If not then it's simply adding a sprite to a layer which isn't itself added to the scene... hence no sprite appearing

Comment: here are some things you should check: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/09/reasons-node-show/

Comment: @simonthumper The Survival layer is declared in the HUDLayer as sL and therefore, when I call the method I do `[sL fire];` in the HUDLayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everybody, Solved it in some mysterious way. Thanks for the help anyway. I think I declared the layer in a wrong way.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

to add a sprite in cocos2d do something like this

```
CCNode *parent = [self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode];
[parent addChild:sprite];
```

if that doesnt fix it, make sure the point where you are adding it is on the screen and try changing the z value to see if that helps

EDIT

add this under where you import files

```
enum {
kTagParentNode = 1,
};
```

Comment: Sorry If my question is ridiculous but what does the kTagParentNode mean?

Comment: If I add a sprite in the init method everything works perfectly. But not in the void.

Comment: What is Survival? A layer? Or a node? Is survival added to a layer? It might be your position is messed up. Position is relative to the parent node not the screen position so you have to take that into account.

Comment: @Sylvan Survival is a layer and it contains a TMXTiledMap